# MongoDB - find one and add a new property

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

Background: Im developing an app that shows analytics for inventory management.
It gets an office EXCEL file uploaded, and as the file uploads the app convert it to an array of JSONs. Then, it comapers each json object with the objects in the DB, change its quantity according to the XLS file, and add a timestamp to the stamps array which contain the changes in qunatity.

For example:

```
{"_id":"5c3f531baf4fe3182cf4f1f2",
"sku":123456,
"product_name":"Example",
"product_cost":10,
"product_price":60,
"product_quantity":100,
"Warehouse":4,
"stamps":[]
}
```

after the XLS upload, lets say we sold 10 units, it should look like that:

```
{"_id":"5c3f531baf4fe3182cf4f1f2",
"sku":123456,
"product_name":"Example",
"product_cost":10,
"product_price":60,
"product_quantity":90,
"Warehouse":4,
"stamps":[{"1548147562": -10}]
}
```

Right now i cant find the right commands for mongoDB to do it, Im developing in Node.js and Angular, Would love to read some ideas.

```
for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
 ProductsDatabase.findOneAndUpdate(
      {"_id": products[i]['id']},
      //CHANGE QUANTITY AND ADD A STAMP

...
}
```

Comment: hey Elad, welcome here,
so, in your case can you also let us know, the object you want to push to `stamps` in future yu want t update that too? or only push to that array?

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty only push and read it by angular

Comment: @chridam the Excel file has the accurate quantity , some products will sell some wil not, i cant know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongoose's [findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) to update the existing value of a document.

```
"use strict";


const ids = products.map(x => x._id);

let operations = products.map(xlProductData => {

  return ProductsDatabase.find({
    _id: {
      $in: ids
    }
  }).then(products => {

    return products.map(productData => {
      return ProductsDatabase.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: xlProductData.id // or product._id
      }, {
        sku: xlProductData.sku,
        product_name: xlProductData.product_name,
        product_cost: xlProductData.product_cost,
        product_price: xlProductData.product_price,
        Warehouse: xlProductData.Warehouse,
        product_quantity: productData.product_quantity - xlProductData.product_quantity,

        $push: {
          stamps: {
            [new Date().getTime()]: -1 * xlProductData.product_quantity
          }
        },

        updated_at: new Date()
      }, {
        upsert: false,
        returnNewDocument: true
      });
    });

  });

});

Promise.all(operations).then(() => {
  console.log('All good');
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('err ', err);
});
```

Comment: i need it to calculate the difference between quantites and push it to the stamp array

Comment: @EladDahan updated my answer for the timestamp and quantities to be dynamic

Comment: you are awsome but it still not good, in the XL file i get the current quantity , lets say it was 100pcs in stock and now its 90pcs. if i do what you suggest, ill get quantity of 10pcs in stock

Comment: @EladDahan I think now, it updates all values appropriately

Comment: @EladDahan in that case you can do `xlProductData.product_quantity` instead of `productData.product_quantity - xlProductData.product_quantity`

Comment: @chridam yes you're right. Updated my answer for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would need two operations here. The first will be to get an array of documents from the db that match the ones in the JSON array. From the list you compare the `'product_quantity'` keys and if there is a change, create a new array of objects with the product id and change in quantity.

The second operation will be an update which uses this new array with the change in quantity for each matching product.

Armed with this new array of updated product properties, it would be ideal to use a bulk update for this as looping through the list and sending
each update request to the server can be computationally costly.

Consider using the [`bulkWrite`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite) method which is on the model. This accepts an array of write operations and executes each of them of which a typical update operation 
for your use case would have the following structure

```
{ updateOne :
    {
    "filter" : <document>,
    "update" : <document>,
    "upsert" : <boolean>,
    "collation": <document>,
    "arrayFilters": [ <filterdocument1>, ... ]
    }
}
```

So your operations would follow this pattern:

```
(async () => {

    let bulkOperations = []
    const ids = products.map(({ id }) => id)
    const matchedProducts =  await ProductDatabase.find({ 
        '_id': { '$in': ids }
    }).lean().exec()

    for(let product in products) {
        const [matchedProduct, ...rest] = matchedProducts.filter(p => p._id === product.id)
        const { _id, product_quantity } = matchedProduct
        const changeInQuantity = product.product_quantity - product_quantity

        if (changeInQuantity !== 0) {
            const stamps = { [(new Date()).getTime()] : changeInQuantity }

            bulkOperations.push({
                'updateOne': {
                    'filter': { _id },
                    'update': { 
                        '$inc': { 'product_quantity': changeInQuantity },
                        '$push': { stamps }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }

    const bulkResult = await ProductDatabase.bulkWrite(bulkOperations)
    console.log(bulkResult)

})()
```

Comment: I cant tell if the change in quantity will be 10, i need it to comapre it to the current quantity in the DB

Comment: @EladDahan You would need two operations: one to find the matching docs from DB with the JSON array and the next to update the ones with the change in quantity as described by the new edit. Otherwise I don't see any other way to do this in a single operation, you would need two calls to the server; 1) to retrieve matching docs and 2) update the ones which only have a change in quantity